# ReactiveMongo: How to use FindAndModify to read a document and increment a value atomically

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I need to read a document and increment a value atomically. I know ReactiveMongo provides `FindAndModify` and looked at [this example](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/blob/master/driver/samples/SimpleUseCasesSample.scala#L186-212). If you look at the `findAndModify` method in the example, you'll see that it just finds the documents that match a condition and then updates them with a new value.

How do I set a new value based on the old one? In other words, I need to read a value, increment it, and eventually update the document [atomically]:

```
def incrementValue() = {
  val selector = BSONDocument("name" -> "Joe")
  val modifier = BSONDocument(
    "$set" -> BSONDocument("version" -> ???)) // how do I increment the old
                                              // value of 'version' by 1? 
  val command = FindAndModify(
    collection.name,
    selector,
    Update(modifier, false))
```

Comment: If this is your whole findandModify query then I strongly recommend you use a normal update for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$inc` instead of `$set`. Here you can find the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/). Of course it also works with `findAndModify`.

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful.